# Tabela variável

Tags: javascript, table

Não sei se é possível, mas eu gostaria de criar uma tabela que de acordo com meus dados ela criaria o número de linhas e colunas, e depois fosse possível eu digitar valores nessas células. Criar uma planilha também seria possível. No entanto não achei nada até agora que pudesse me ajudar. Alguém sabe alguma forma, eu trabalho com linguagem HTML/Javascript.

Comment: algo como isto ? http://jsfiddle.net/4v1ewLsb/1/  de acordo com quais dados você  deseja criar esta tabela ? coloque essa informação no seu post também

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, muito obrigado.

Comment: Depois de algum jeito eu consigo utilizar os dados que eu digitar nos retangulos?

Answer (score 2):

Este tipo de cenários tende a ser complexo quando vamos desenvolver algo de raiz.

O melhor é partir de um *PlugIn* já existente que assente numa *FrameWork* fortemente utilizada, assim temos uma base que já lida com a maior parte dos problemas e temos a garantia que ajuda não vai faltar quando "batermos na parede".

## [editable-table](https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table)

> Este pequeno (3 KB, <120 linhas) plugin para jQuery transforma qualquer tabela em uma planilha editável.

Partindo de uma tabela em HTML, basta instanciar o *PlugIn* na mesma:

```html
<table id="mainTable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Cost</th><th>Profit</th><th>Fun</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Car</td><td>100</td><td>200</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bike</td><td>330</td><td>240</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Plane</td><td>430</td><td>540</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Yacht</td><td>100</td><td>200</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Segway</td><td>330</td><td>240</td><td>1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><th><strong>TOTAL</strong></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

```js
$('#oMeuId').editableTableWidget();
```

## Exemplo

```js
/*global $, window*/
$.fn.editableTableWidget = function(options) {
  'use strict';
  return $(this).each(function() {
    var buildDefaultOptions = function() {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.editableTableWidget.defaultOptions);
        opts.editor = opts.editor.clone();
        return opts;
      },
      activeOptions = $.extend(buildDefaultOptions(), options),
      ARROW_LEFT = 37,
      ARROW_UP = 38,
      ARROW_RIGHT = 39,
      ARROW_DOWN = 40,
      ENTER = 13,
      ESC = 27,
      TAB = 9,
      element = $(this),
      editor = activeOptions.editor.css('position', 'absolute').hide().appendTo(element.parent()),
      active,
      showEditor = function(select) {
        active = element.find('td:focus');
        if (active.length) {
          editor.val(active.text())
            .removeClass('error')
            .show()
            .offset(active.offset())
            .css(active.css(activeOptions.cloneProperties))
            .width(active.width())
            .height(active.height())
            .focus();
          if (select) {
            editor.select();
          }
        }
      },
      setActiveText = function() {
        var text = editor.val(),
          evt = $.Event('change'),
          originalContent;
        if (active.text() === text || editor.hasClass('error')) {
          return true;
        }
        originalContent = active.html();
        active.text(text).trigger(evt, text);
        if (evt.result === false) {
          active.html(originalContent);
        }
      },
      movement = function(element, keycode) {
        if (keycode === ARROW_RIGHT) {
          return element.next('td');
        } else if (keycode === ARROW_LEFT) {
          return element.prev('td');
        } else if (keycode === ARROW_UP) {
          return element.parent().prev().children().eq(element.index());
        } else if (keycode === ARROW_DOWN) {
          return element.parent().next().children().eq(element.index());
        }
        return [];
      };
    editor.blur(function() {
        setActiveText();
        editor.hide();
      }).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === ENTER) {
          setActiveText();
          editor.hide();
          active.focus();
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
        } else if (e.which === ESC) {
          editor.val(active.text());
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          editor.hide();
          active.focus();
        } else if (e.which === TAB) {
          active.focus();
        } else if (this.selectionEnd - this.selectionStart === this.value.length) {
          var possibleMove = movement(active, e.which);
          if (possibleMove.length > 0) {
            possibleMove.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
          }
        }
      })
      .on('input paste', function() {
        var evt = $.Event('validate');
        active.trigger(evt, editor.val());
        if (evt.result === false) {
          editor.addClass('error');
        } else {
          editor.removeClass('error');
        }
      });
    element.on('click keypress dblclick', showEditor)
      .css('cursor', 'pointer')
      .keydown(function(e) {
        var prevent = true,
          possibleMove = movement($(e.target), e.which);
        if (possibleMove.length > 0) {
          possibleMove.focus();
        } else if (e.which === ENTER) {
          showEditor(false);
        } else if (e.which === 17 || e.which === 91 || e.which === 93) {
          showEditor(true);
          prevent = false;
        } else {
          prevent = false;
        }
        if (prevent) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

    element.find('td').prop('tabindex', 1);

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      if (editor.is(':visible')) {
        editor.offset(active.offset())
          .width(active.width())
          .height(active.height());
      }
    });
  });

};
$.fn.editableTableWidget.defaultOptions = {
  cloneProperties: ['padding', 'padding-top', 'padding-bottom', 'padding-left', 'padding-right',
    'text-align', 'font', 'font-size', 'font-family', 'font-weight',
    'border', 'border-top', 'border-bottom', 'border-left', 'border-right'
  ],
  editor: $('<input>')
};

$('#mainTable').editableTableWidget();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mainTable" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Profit</th>
      <th>Fun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Car</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bike</td>
      <td>330</td>
      <td>240</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plane</td>
      <td>430</td>
      <td>540</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yacht</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Segway</td>
      <td>330</td>
      <td>240</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th><strong>TOTAL</strong>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```